# nginx rewrite rule to prepend something to a url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, mobify

I want to rewrite all my JPG file URLs using mobify CDN. For that, all I have to do is prepend the URL

`https://ir0.mobify.com/jpg50/` to my existing URL. So for example, if I have the URL

`http://xxx.yyy.com/wp-content/uploads/2290/07/abc.png` then the user has to be redirected to

`https://ir0.mobify.com/jpg50/http://xxx.yyy.com/wp-content/uploads/2290/07/abc.jpg`

I wrote the following code in my nginx config. I tested the regexs at regexlib and they seem to be fine.Still do not understand what is wrong with my config. Please help.

`location ~ \.jpg$
{
     rewrite ^http://(.*).jpg$ https://ir0.mobify.com/jpg50/$uri last;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
location ~ \.jpg$ { 
    return 301 https://ir0.mobify.com/jpg50$request_uri; 
}
```

Comment: Well, that looks like it should do the trick. But, doing this via nginx sends the URL into a redirect loop. That happens as when mobify has not cached the image_(first time access by any user for a given file)_, it tries to fetch it directly from the server and when it tries to do that, it is automatically redirected to the prepended URL and hence the redirect loop. So, I guess it would be better to handle this at the application layer. if you have any solution to this redirect-loop problem, please share.

Comment: You will have to send a cookie or header from Mobify to Nginx and test on this before redirecting.

Comment: Well, mobify is beyond my control so I guess will have to handle it at the application layer